# Will Keynote Remote work with a MacBook in closed clamshell mode?

Tags: keynote, closed-clamshell

For my next presentation, I plan to use Keynote Remote so I can control a Keynote presentation with my iPhone. Will this work while the MacBook Air is in 'closed clamshell' mode? If yes, are there any caveats?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. Since the MacBook is essentially still on with just the display deactivated, Keynote Remote will be fully-functional.